# Probability of Alice getting ice cream twice in a month given constraints

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Here is a practice problem I attempted to solve:

> Alice gets ice cream twice a month. Each pair of dates during the month is equally likely, except that the she never gets ice cream twice a day for health reasons. Assume a month has 28 days and starts on a Sunday.
>
> **In a given month, what is the probability that Alice will get ice cream twice in the same week?**

My reasoning is the following. Consider an arbitary week. The probability that Alice gets ice cream during the week is $7/28$. The probability that she gets ice cream again that week is $6/28$ given that she won't go twice on the same day. Finally, there are four weeks in a month. My answer was

$$
\mathbb{P}\{\text{Alice gets ice cream twice in same week}\} = 4\Big(\frac{7}{28}\Big)\Big(\frac{6}{28}\Big) \approx 0.214
$$

However, the solution is as follows. There are ${28 \choose 2}$ possible pairs of dates in a month, and ${7 \choose 2}$ pairs in a given week. So the probability is

$$
\mathbb{P}\{\text{Alice gets ice cream twice in same week}\} 
= 
4 \Bigg[ {7 \choose 2} / {28 \choose 2} \Bigg] = 9/2 \approx 0.222
$$

I understanding the logic of the solution, but I don't see why my logic is wrong. Given that my probability is lower, perhaps I am under-counting.

Comment: The $\frac 6{28}$ should be $\frac 6{27}$.

Comment: Side note:  your phrasing isn't great.  It isn't true that "the probability that Alice gets ice cream during the week is $\frac 7{28}$".  I understand what you intended, but it took me a few readings.

Comment: Perfect. I thought my approach was valid, and I just made a small mistake. Thanks. If you make that an answer, I'll accept. You're right that my phrasing is imprecise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is fine, but the phrasing is a bit off and there's a simple arithmetic error.

I'd model the problem this way: suppose Alice starts the month by putting the numbers $1-28$ in a hat and drawing two dates without replacement.  The probability that the first choice falls in a specified week is $\frac 7{28}$.  The probability that the second choice also falls in that same week is then $\frac 6{27}$.  As there are $4$ weeks it follows that the answer is $$4\times \frac 7{28}\times \frac 6{27}=\frac 29$$